# How to trigger back-pressure in rx-java

Tags: rx-java

rx-java version: 2.1.1

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[100000];
    Arrays.fill(ints, 1);
    Flowable.fromArray(ints).onBackpressureBuffer(1, () -> {
      System.out.println("Overflow");
    }).subscribe(events -> {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println(events);
    });
  }
```

With a slow consumer and a rather small buffer capacity won't trigger action in overflow. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it happens because you are using only one thread, operators usually apply current thread if nothing specified explicitly. Try to add `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` before subscribing.

Comment: `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` or any other schedulers won't work

Comment: Also subscribe using `DefaultSubscriber` instead of `Consumer` won't do as well.